# IN HTML5: How to rotate an image to 360 degrees in the centre of canvas keping other objects stationary

Tags: html, animation, canvas, html5-canvas, css-transitions

I am trying to create an animation in which an image in the middle of the canvas has to be rotated by 360 degree while keeping other objects on the canvas stationary,basically i want  to give fan like rotating effect to image but it is not working in my case.Following the code snippet that i am using.

assume canvas size is 400 by 200

```
 var surface;
 var img = new Image();
 var angle = 0;
 img.src = "images/teddy.png";
 surface = document.getElementById("canvas");
 var ctx = surface.getContext('2d');

 // Clear the canvas to White
ctx .fillStyle = "rgb(255,255,255)";
ctx .fillRect(0, 0, surface.width, surface.height);
// Save the current context
ctx .save();
// Translate to the center point of our image
ctx .translate(happy.width * 0.5, happy.height * 0.5);
ctx .rotate(DegToRad(angle,surfaceContext)); //calling function here  
ctx .translate(-(happy.width * 0.5), -(happy.height * 0.5));
ctx .drawImage(happy, 200, 100);
angle++;
ctx.restore();
```

above code is being called using setInterval(loop, 10);

It rotates the image on the diameter of 100px at postion 200px on x-axis but what i want is that image should keep rotating on its current postion

I am new to HTML5 so please endure me :)

Thanks
~Simer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume this is what you want:
http://jsfiddle.net/zH9yy/

```
var render, loop, t, dt,
    DEG2RAD = Math.PI / 180,
    cvs = document.querySelector('canvas'),
    ctx = cvs.getContext('2d'),
    teddy = new Image(),
    heart = new Image(),
    angle = 0,
    reqAnimFrame = 
        window.requestAnimationFrame ||
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.oRequestAnimationFrame;

cvs.width = 400;
cvs.height = 200;

teddy.src = 'https://d3qcduphvv2yxi.cloudfront.net/assets/1204584/view_small/43b95bee9e4e9a8a1effcdc3d401774a.jpg';

heart.src = 'http://a.dryicons.com/files/graphics_previews/flower_heart.jpg';

render = function (timestamp) {
    dt = timestamp - t;
    t = timestamp;

    // Clear the canvas to White
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255,255,255)";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, cvs.width, cvs.height);

    // draw heart
    ctx.drawImage(heart, -20, -120);

    // draw teddy
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(cvs.width/2, cvs.height/2); // move cursor to canvas center
    ctx.rotate(DEG2RAD * angle); // rotate canvas
    ctx.drawImage(teddy, -teddy.width/2, -teddy.height/2); // draw img center at cursor center
    angle += dt / 16.67 * 6; // increment angle ~ 360 deg/sec
    ctx.restore();
};

loop = function (timestamp) {
    reqAnimFrame(loop);
    render(timestamp);
};

t = Date.now();
loop(t);
```

​

Comment: Yes exactly this is(http://jsfiddle.net/zH9yy/) what i want but i was looking to do it using some other way without requiring " reqAnimFrame ". so i managed to do it in other way. have a look at this  http://jsfiddle.net/p9GyW/